# A little bit of/a little

Tags: word-choice

Can I use "a bit of +food" and "little +food" in my sentence?

"Personally, I think a bit of meat isn't bad for us. I like eating little beef/meat."

Comment: Please note: "a bit of " as used in your sentence  mostly BrE, and very used. In AmE, we'd say: a little meat. In any case, it is: **a bit of meat, a little beef**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subtle but important difference between **a little X** or **a bit of X** and **little X**.

**I enjoy eating a little/a bit of beef** means that I enjoy eating a small amount of beef (maybe if I ate a lot of beef, I would not enjoy it).  This has a "positive" connotation: I only have a small amount of beef, but I enjoy it.  Think of it like "some".

**I enjoy eating little beef** means that I enjoy the *fact* that I do not eat much beef.  This has a kind of "negative" connotation - it sounds like I don't have enough beef, so using "little X" with "enjoy" is a little strange.  Think of it like "hardly any".

References:

- https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/a-little-a-few.html
- https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/us/english-usage/what-is-the-difference-between-little-and-a-little